# Sinônimo para a tag Reflexão e Reflection (tradução)

Tags: debate, status-pronto, tradução, tags-sinônimas

Existem duas TAGs iguais, que talvez acidentalmente foram criadas devido a tradução:

- [reflection](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reflection) (em inglês)
- [reflexão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reflex%c3%a3o) (em português)
- [reflexo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reflexo) (em português)

Porém acredito que a tradução mais adequada seja [reflexo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reflexo) no sentido de refletir em códigos a existência da classe abstrata e suas relações. Já a palavra [reflexão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reflex%c3%a3o) me parece inadequada apesar de ser também uma tradução para [reflection](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reflection) pois representa o conceito de raciocínio, meditação.

Comment: "*compilar ou não compilar? Eis a questão*" - daria uma ótima pergunta para a tag reflexão.

Comment: *Reflexo* é o que acontece quando o médico dá uma martelada no joelho. Para mais informações, assista o respectivo episódio do Chaves.

Comment: Reflexo também é o que se vê no espelho, também é o que se tenta fazer quando se abstrai algo, apesar da reflexão necessárias para se chegar a abstração, o reflexo é o resultado final.

Answer (score 10):

O termo comumente usado é *reflexão*. Vide [Wikipédia](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflex%C3%A3o_(programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o)). Buscar no Google por "reflexo java", por exemplo, não traz absolutamente nenhum resultado.

Sou a favor de manter a *tag* [reflexão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reflex%c3%a3o) como primária e fazer da [reflection](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reflection) um sinônimo para a mesma.

A não ser que a comunidade discorde.

Comment: sem dúvida temos termos que são excluidos e acabam infelizmente se tornando padrão, um exemplo que aprendi a 25 anos atrás é o favor `debugar` não há termo mais feio que este, muitos insistem em usar no lugar do `depurar` que seria mais adequado ao nosso idioma.

Comment: @Delfino Verdade. Eu mesmo passei a usar a palavra *depurar* sempre, mas às vezes tenho que explicar o que é. Bem, coloquei as duas tags como sinônimos.